# Electrical power in series and parallel

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, power, batteries

I have confused myself massively and would like some help.

In my situation we have a cell with emf $V$ and no internal resistance, we hook up 2 lamps of resistance $R$ ohms in series, I have calculated the power of the circuit to be $V^2$/$2R$, meaning each bulb has a power of $V^2$$/$$4R$. Now if we put these bulbs in parallel with each other, the total current now becomes twice that it was before, and the power of each bulb is $V^2$$/$$R$, which is 4 times that of the bulb in the original circuit.

Now this is where the confusion begins, say we use the formula $P = VI$, that means the power across one bulb in series arrangement is $VI$, and for paralell, the bulb will get twice the PD, and its current will be the same, (as the total current doubles but only half goes into each bulb), leaving us with a power of $2VI$, which is obviously only double the original power. Now I would like to ask, is twice or 4 times the correct answer and could someone correct my misunderstanding please?

Comment: For series conenction, the bulb does not have V across its terminals so P=VI is not the power of one bulb.

Comment: So it doubles? and not quadruples?

Comment: The current coming out of the voltage source is quadrupled, not doubled, in the parallel case. Think about it: the load has changed from 2R to R/2.

Comment: Silly me, i was getting it mixed up with when you go from 1 bulb in series to 2 bulbs in paralell, thats when you get half the load, this is another factor of 2 higher up, so then it goes down by factor of 4.

Comment: Refer to two equations; one equation gives the equivalent resistance of resistors in series and the other equation gives the equivalent resistance of resistors in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

> Now if we put these bulbs in parallel with each other, the total current now becomes twice that it was before

This is not true. The current with the lamps in series is $V/(2R)$. The total current with the lamps in parallel is $V/(R/2)=2V/R$, and half that for each lamp.